# off-canvas menu designed by helix3 disappears in mobile mode of my site

Tags: joomla, responsive-design, helix, off-canvas-menu

I'm building a persian (rtl) website with an offcanvas menu using helix3. The site works fine in all modes (mobile/desktop) when testing with "responsive web design Tester" or other testing tools. But when surfing the site with tablet or ipad, the offcanvas menu appears for a second or 2 and then disappears surprisingly (It works fine over iPhone 7).
I am using helix3, joomla 3.8.10 and jquery v1.12.0.

my site: [www.bapgroup.ir](https://www.bapgroup.ir/)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Detect the browser is for mobile or desktop. here you can find how to do it : https://coderwall.com/p/i817wa/one-line-function-to-detect-mobile-devices-with-javascript then set `display: none` for canvas if the browser is for mobile.

Comment: The link in the mentioned url gives a 404 error. In addition, I wanna show canvas menu in mobile mode and disappear it it desktop mode.